# display notification number in MAC cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa

i want to display notification (like the number that exist when a application is minimized in utorrent or itunes (when u have some update) or in outlook the number of unread mails).
I am using this for a messaging application so when the application is minimized and i receive a message then it must display the number of unread messages.

Do i need to use apple push notification as in the case of iPhone applications if so is there some other way ?
Thanks

Comment: Is a badge on the Dock icon what you mean by a notification?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [NSDockTile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See also the [Dock Tile Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/intro/dockintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986).

Answer (score 1):

If your refering to the little red badge in the top right corner of an application dock icon then thats called the Dock Badge Label, You can easly set this through code, Because I do all my programing in Cocoa Applescript / AppleScript Objective C i struggle with C so Ill use a simple code:

You should be able to set the Dock Icon Badge with this:

```
[[NSApp dockTile] setBadgeLabel: @"1"];

// Sets the Dock Badge to "1"
```

(PS I just guessed this because I had to mentally convert this to Objective C) but this should work